# My join table doesn't seem to be working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model

**my models:**

```
class CardSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :conversion
  has_one :card_signup, :through => :conversion

class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :conversions
  has_many :card_signups, :through => :conversions

class Conversion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card_signup
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**my migration:**

```
class AddCardSignupConversions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table (:conversions, :id => false) do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :card_signup_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :conversions
  end
end
```

Now, I can successfully look up:

```
User.find(x).conversions
CardSignup.find(x).conversion
```

However, I can't add any objects to these links. Not sure why.. I tried this :

```
User.last.conversions << CardSignup.last
```

Which returned :

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Conversion(#2183228680) expected, got CardSignup(#2183113520)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it!

```
class CardSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
  # add_column :card_signups, :converted_by, :integer   # Add this to your migration
  belongs_to :converted_by, :class_name => "User"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversions, :foreign_key => :converted_by, :class_name => "CardSignup"
```

This allows me to have my own unique name for the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Why have you declared keys as strings in conversions table? Usually integers are used. This could be a cause of a problem

`t.string :user_id`
`t.string :card_signup_id`

Edit:
Also you're trying to add CardSignup to conversions association. This definitely will not work. Btw: error says the same.

Comment: Use `references ` migration helper for example: `t.references :user`

Comment: Same error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Conversion(#2184375980) expected, got CardSignup(#2183621000)` . Also `t.references` simply created `t.integer :user_id` .

Comment: As I said before the base error is that you'r trying to add CardSignup model to conversions array it is impossible ant it it major application design flaw.

Comment: Ah, then how would you recommend creating a join table with a unique name for the join. I have to make it unique because these two objects are already relationally connected by a different association. Hey, thanks by the way for your help iafonov.